# C# - Calling a struct constructor that has all defaulted parameters

Tags: c#, struct, optional-parameters, default-constructor

I ran into this issue today when creating a `struct` to hold a bunch of data. Here is an example:

```
public struct ExampleStruct
{
    public int Value { get; private set; }

    public ExampleStruct(int value = 1)
        : this()
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

Looks fine and dandy. The problem is when I try to use this constructor without specifying a value and desiring to use the defaulted value of 1 for the parameter:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ExampleStruct example1 = new ExampleStruct();

    Console.WriteLine(example1.Value);
}
```

This code outputs `0` and does not output `1`. The reason is that all structs have public parameter-less constructors. So, like how I'm calling `this()` my explicit constructor, in `Main`, that same thing occurs where `new ExampleStruct()` is actually calling `ExampleStruct()` but not calling `ExampleStruct(int value = 1)`. Since it does that, it uses `int`'s default value of 0 as `Value`.

To make matters worse, my actual code is checking to see that `int value = 1` parameter is within a valid range within the constructor. Add this to the `ExampleStruct(int value = 1)` constructor above:

```
if(value < 1 || value > 3)
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Value is out of range");
}
```

So, as it stands right now, the default constructor actually created an object that is invalid in the context I need it for. Anyone know how I can either:

- A. Call the `ExampleStruct(int value = 1)` constructor.
- B. Modify how the default values are populated for the `ExampleStruct()` constructor.
- C. Some other suggestion/option.

Also, I am aware that I could use a field like this instead of my `Value` property:

```
public readonly int Value;
```

But my philosophy is to use fields privately unless they are `const` or `static`.

Lastly, the reason I'm using a `struct` instead of a `class` is because this is simply an object to hold non-mutable data, should be fully populated when it is constructed, and when passed as a parameter, should not be able to be `null` (since it is passed by value as a `struct`), which is what struct's are designed for.

Comment: That's not necessarily the full reason to use a `struct`, you can still do all that with a `class` and just throw `ArgumentNullException`.  The main reasons to use `strcut` are outlined by the MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx

Comment: Some day I should blog about all the CRAZY examples there are with the use of structs! thanks for this one!

Comment: notice that with every call you are making a copy of your data since its a struct..

Comment: Instead of having the range 1-3, have the range 0-2 and have a property which modifies the return value to be in the correct range ;)

Comment: @Porges: you could do that, but that would be pretty messy and would have to be well documented.  I prefer the nullable initialized field instead with a default on proeprty accessor.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Actually, MSDN has some good guidance on `struct`

> Consider defining a structure instead of a class if instances of the
>   type are small and commonly short-lived or are commonly embedded in
>   other objects.
>
> Do not define a structure unless the type has all of the following
>   characteristics:
>
> It logically represents a single value, similar to primitive types
>   (integer, double, and so on).
>
> It has an instance size smaller than 16 bytes.
>
> It is immutable.
>
> It will not have to be boxed frequently.

Notice that they are considerations for *considering* a `struct`, and its never a "this *should* always be a struct".  That is because the choice to use a `struct` can have performance and usage implications (both positive and negative) and should be chosen carefully.

Notice in particular that they don't recommend `struct` for things > 16 bytes (then the cost of copying becomes more expensive than copying a reference).

Now, for your case, there is really no good way to do this other than to create a factory to generate a `struct` for you in a default state or to do some sort of `trick` in your property to fool it into initializing on first use.

Remember, a `struct` is supposed to work such that `new X()` == `default(X)`, that is, a newly constructed `struct` will contain the default values for all fields of that `struct`.  This is pretty evident, since C# will *not* let you define a parameterless constructor for a `struct`, though it is curious that they allow all arguments to be defaulted without a warning.

Thus, I'd actually suggest you stick with a `class` and make it immutable and just check for `null` on the methods that it gets passed to.

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    // have property expose the "default" if not yet set
    public int Value { get; private set; }

    // remove default, doesn't work
    public ExampleStruct(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

**However**, if you absolutely *must* have a `struct` for other reasons - but please consider the costs of `struct` such as copy-casts, etc - you could do this:

```
public struct ExampleStruct
{
    private int? _value;

    // have property expose the "default" if not yet set
    public int Value
    {
        get { return _value ?? 1; }
    }

    // remove default, doesn't work
    public ExampleStruct(int value)
        : this()
    {
        _value = value;
    }
}
```

Notice that by default, the `Nullable<int>` will be `null` (that is, `HasValue == false`), thus if this is true, we didn't set it yet, and can use the null-coalescing operator to return our default of `1` instead.  If we *did* set it in the constructor, it will be non-null and take that value instead...

Comment: Thanks, James. I ended up changing it to a `class`. Methods that have `ExampleClass` as a parameter have it defaulted to `ExampleClass example = null`. I put documentation stating that if it is set to `null`, it defaults to `example ?? new ExampleClass()`. Since it is a class now, it ends up calling the proper constructor of `public ExampleClass(int value = 1)`.

Comment: Good tip on the `?` and null-coalescing operator. This provided me with a solution for `Size.Empty` where `Height` and `Width` could have a default value of `Double.NaN` ...thus truly an **empty** `Size`.

Comment: Regarding performance related to structs, there have been some updates to the language since this was last edited: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/the-in-modifier-and-the-readonly-structs-in-c/

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's good design to have a `struct` `ExampleStruct` such that

```
default(ExampleStruct)
```

i.e. the value where all instance fields are zero/false/null, is **not** a valid value of the struct. And as you know, when you say

```
new ExampleStruct()
```

that's exactly the same as `default(ExampleStruct)` and gives you the value of your struct where all fields (including "generated" fields from auto-properties) are zero.

Maybe you could do this:

```
public struct ExampleStruct
{
  readonly int valueMinusOne;

  public int Value { get { return valueMinusOne + 1; } }

  public ExampleStruct(int value)
  {
    valueMinusOne = value - 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: `"I don't think it's good design to have a struct ExampleStruct such that" [...]"` Actually, it's not only bad design, it's not even possible; the language won't let you do anything else.

Comment: why not have an empty constructor setting it to 1?

Comment: @CarloV.Dango Try doing that and see for yourself.  You'll get a compiler error.

Comment: C# using structs is like coding c++ yikes!

Comment: @Servy I know the default is always the value where everything is zero. I'm saying it's bad to _consider_ this default value "invalid". My extended version of the answer tries to translate the value such that the default `1` is stored internally as zero. Somewhat like the `DateTime` struct where `default(DateTime)` (with `Ticks` field zero) represents 0001-01-01.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the compiler is actually picking the automatic default ctor for structs here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288208(v=vs.71).aspx, rather than using your ctor with the default values.

added references:
http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx (Optional parameters section)

Comment: 7.5.3.2 Better function member in the c# spec.

Comment: I'm simply saying that you should have included that in your answer.  it's clearly *right*, it's just not well explained.

Comment: Fair enough. Btw, same goes for classes, only that you have to add the default ctor explicitly.

Comment: The exact wording in that spec: _Otherwise if all parameters of `MP` have a corresponding argument whereas default arguments need to be substituted for at least one optional parameter in `MQ` then `MP` is better than `MQ`._

Answer (score 1):

Although some languages (CIL if nothing else) will allow one to define a struct constructor such that `new T()` has fields set to something other than their "all zeroes" defaults, C# and vb.net (and probably most other languages) take the view that since things like array elements and class fields must always be initialized to `default(T)`, and since having them be initialized to something which didn't match `new T()` would be confusing, structures shouldn't define `new T()` to mean something other than `default(T)`.

I would suggest that rather than trying to jinx a default parameter in a parameterized constructor, you simply define a static struct property which returns your desired default value, and replace every occurrence of `new ExampleStruct()` with `ExampleStruct.NiceDefault;`.

**2015 Addendum**

It appears that C# and VB.NET may ease the prohibition against defining parameterless struct constructors.  This may cause a statement like `Dim s = New StructType()` to assign `s` a value which is different from the value given to new array items of type `StructType`.  I'm not terribly keen on the change, given that `new StructType` is often used in places where something analogous to C#'s `default(StructType)` would be more appropriate if it existed.  VB.NET would allow `Dim s As StructType = Nothing`, but that seems rather hokey.

Answer (score 0):

why do you have `public ExampleStruct(int value = 1) : this()` ?

shouldn't it be `public ExampleStruct(int value = 1)`?  I think the `:this()` is creating the no-parameter constructor.

Comment: It would be worthwhile for you to understand more clearly how `: this()` relates to calling the default constructor.

Comment: Note that his struct uses auto-properties. They introduce "special" backing fields. Therefore the user-defined constructors have to chain `this()` to make things compile.